# PHP FTP_GET downloading distorted .jpg images

Tags: php, image, image-processing, ftp

I have a scenario in which I need to use FTP_GET to recursively download and organize a fair amount of images (usually, 2-3k ~1mb .jpg's at a time).

I've built the entire system and never once actually opened a downloaded image, as the file size is an exact match and no errors or issues had sprung up until now. (D'oh!)

However, as the project is nearing completion...I've noticed that ALL the downloaded images are heavily distorted (but obviously aren't on the remote server).

I'll provide any additional information you may need, but here's what I think is relevant.

A new connection is opened, then a single image is downloaded, then the connection is closed. I know it would be better to download multiple files per connection, but due to certain circumstance this is an easier option. Is it possible I'm somehow closing the connection too early? (even though the filesize matches?) I'm using the regular, "blocking" ftp_get as opposed to ftp_nb_get...so, I wouldn't suspect this as an issue, but figured that I would mention it anyway.

```
if ( ftp_get($ftp, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
```

The above is the relevant code, which is wrapped in a for each loop. The if statement does eval to true.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's a link to both the original and distorted images, if this helps. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVWaR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me! I had put FTP_ASCII instead of FTP_BINARY.